# How can I set the system clock to GPS time?

Tags: time, ntp, gps

My computer is running Ubuntu 16.04 and has a GPS receiver connected to a USB port.

`gpsmon` shows that the GPS receiver is locked and running.

`sudo gpsmon /dev/ttyUSB0` works great!

Why do I have to use sudo to run gpsmon every time?

Is there a way to set the system clock on Ubuntu 16.04 to the time being reported by the GPS receiver without using NTP?

Comment: Have you taken a look at `pps-tools`, or tutorials like [gps on raspberry pi 3](https://gary-dalton.github.io/RaspberryPi-projects/rpi3_gps.html), or [My ADSB Receiver Box – GPS Precision Time](https://www.mictronics.de/2016/12/gps-precision-time-upgrade-1/)

Comment: To remove the requirement for sudo, add your username to the dialout group. `sudo adduser username dialout`

Answer (score 1):

> BTW, why do I have to use sudo to run gpsmon every time?

Most likely, your normal user account doesn't have privileges to /dev/ttyUSB0.

From the command line, type:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And it will return something like:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Jan  2 20:46 ttyUSB0
```

The "root" part is the user that owns the file, the "dialout" is a group associated with the device. You need to add your user account to the group "dialout" then you wont need to start gpsmon with sudo.

This should get you going:

```
usermod -a -G dialout yourusername
```

Hope this helps...