# I need to set my system's clock using a gps receiver

Tags: nvidia, gps

I'm trying to set the system clock on an NVIDIA Jetson using a USB connection to an Advanced Navigation Spatial FOG Dual. I found the following script from a previously answered question:

...

```
#!/bin/bash
#date -s '02/15/2023'
sleep 1
pkill ntpd
pkill gpsd
gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0
sleep 2
GPSDATE=`gpspipe -w | head -10 | grep TPV | sed -r 's/.*"time":"([^"]*)".*/\1/' | head -1`
echo $GPSDATE
date -s "$GPSDATE"
#/usr/sbin/ntpd
```

...

The script executes, but does not set the system set the clock accordingly.

Comment: Did you install gpsd?

Comment: I did, and I can see the data through xgps. I just isn't allowing me to set my system clock to the gps.

Comment: Are you running this script as sudo/root? How does $GPSDATE look like?

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/988514/how-can-i-set-the-system-clock-to-gps-time